# Display a WebView

Tags: android

Has anyone any idea how could I obtain a view that has the following description:
At the top at the page there is a custom test , and below there is displayed the content from a url .Currently my layout is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
    <TextView  
        android:id="@id+/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the on create of the application tight to this layout I get the TextView with findViewById and set the text for it. Similar I get the WebView and call loadUrl("url") for it, but the behavior is not the expected one. At first the text set is briefly displayed and then a fullscreen browser page with the content from the passed url is shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `android:layout_weight='1'` to the WebView.

Comment: It works. One thing though, the webview is not below the text , but the text seems to be rendered on the surface of the webview.

Comment: Hrmm, I just created a test application and it worked for me.  Perhaps there's something else in your code causing the problem?